# Loading a Rails project from a different Rails project

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-3

I would like to create an application (`X`) which will analyse  model details of a given application.

Ex: Say I have a Rails app called `blog`, and it has classes like `post`

```
#post.rb
#db columns -> title, desc
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base

end
```

So in my `X` application , when the path is given of `blog`, it should read the models of the `blog` and should come up with its stats (something like Ruby code quality tools).

Example: it should return the columns if the `Post` class, like `List.columns`

But my problem is, since my `X` application is in a different environment than the `blog` application, how can I load the `blog` application models and access the functionality as I'm running the `blog` application from its console itself?

Because lots of Ruby code quality gems are reading the source code as string, but what I want is to use its functionalities as its accessing from the console.

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the perfect set of requirements for using an API.  Just set up your `blog` controllers to respond to json and then you can make API calls from `X` to `blog` to get the information you need.

There are quite a few resources out there for creating an API within your controllers.  For Rails 3, I'd recommend Rails 3 In Action by Ryan Bigg and Yehuda Katz: http://manning.com/katz/.  There are also numerous blogs, tutorials, etc if you search around.